# Why window size out of screen tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a billing system in my Linux system.in Linux my code works fine and fit to screen
I use place() in code
When I run the same code in windows 10 window size enlarge and shows half of gui
Help me how to fix it
No errors in code but problem in only window size
How to adjust
https://github.com/vijaySai-22/python/tree/main/billing

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class App():
    
    def __init__(self,root):
        ##########--------------Company name-------------##########
        Label(root,text="Green Vegetables Market",font=('Arial',30,'bold','underline'),width=(84),bg="black",fg="white").place(x=0,y=0)
        Label(root,text="Customer Details",font=('Arial',30),width=(84),bg="grey",fg="black").place(x=0,y=60)
        Label(root,text="Enter Custmor Name",font=('Arial',18)).place(x=5,y=120)
        self.c_name=tk.StringVar()
        self.cname_entry=Entry(root,font=('Arial',18),width=(20),textvariable=self.c_name).place(x=245,y=120)
        Label(root,text="Enter contact number",font=('Arial',18)).place(x=525,y=120)
        self.c_phno=tk.StringVar()
        self.phno_entry=Entry(root,font=('Arial',18),width=(20),textvariable=self.c_phno).place(x=769,y=120)
        Label(root,text="Enter Address",font=('Arial',18)).place(x=1045,y=120)
        self.c_add=tk.StringVar()
        self.add_entry=Entry(root,font=('Arial',18),width=(46),textvariable=self.c_add).place(x=1210,y=120)
        # Label(root,text="Age",font=('Arial',18)).place(x=1695,y=120)
        # c_age=tk.StringVar()
        # self.age_entry=Entry(root,font=('Arial',18),width=(4)).place(x=1750,y=120)

        ##########---------------Particulars-------------###########

        Label(root,text="Particulars",font=('Arial',30),fg='black',bg='grey',width=(50)).place(x=5,y=180)
        self.veg=['Potato','Tomato','Carrot','Brinjal','Onions','Cabage','Ginger','Chilli','Garlic','Beetroot']
        self.veg_price=[20,22,30,25,30,30,70,32,60,53]
        self.ck=[None]*len(self.veg)
        self.qty=[None]*len(self.veg)
        self.dis=[None]*len(self.veg)
        self.each_price=[None]*len(self.veg)
        self.y_value=300
        Label(root,text="   ItemNo         Vegetables                           Qty          Discount          Total      ",font=('Arial',23)).place(x=10,y=240)
        for i in range(len(self.veg)):
            self.item_no='Item'+str(i+1)
            Label(root,text=self.item_no,font=('Arial',23)).place(x=50,y=self.y_value)

            self.ck[i]=tk.IntVar()
            name = Checkbutton(root, text = self.veg[i],variable = self.ck[i],
                    onvalue = 1,offvalue = 0,
                    font=('Arial',23),width = 18,anchor="w"
                    ).place(x=180,y=self.y_value)

            self.qty[i]=tk.DoubleVar()
            self.qty[i].set(0)
            Entry(root,font=('Arial',23),textvariable=self.qty[i],width=3).place(x=600,y=self.y_value)
            Label(root,text=".kg",font=('Arial',23)).place(x=660,y=self.y_value)

            self.dis[i]=tk.DoubleVar()
            self.dis[i].set(0)
            Entry(root,font=('Arial',23),textvariable=self.dis[i],width=3).place(x=760,y=self.y_value)
            Label(root,text="% ",font=('Arial',23)).place(x=820,y=self.y_value)

            self.each_price[i]=Label(root,text="0 Rs",font=('Arial',23))
            self.each_price[i].place(x=950,y=self.y_value)
            self.y_value=self.y_value+60
        self.ext=Button(root,text="Exit",font=('Arial',23),bg="red",fg="black",command=self.close).place(x=50,y=900)
        self.clr=Button(root,text="Clear",font=('Arial',23),bg="yellow",fg="black",command=self.clear).place(x=600,y=900)
        self.cal=Button(root,text="Total=",font=('Arial',23),bg="green",fg="black",command=self.calculate).place(x=760,y=900)
        self.total_price=Label(root,text="0 RS",font=('Arial',27),width=9)
        self.total_price.place(x=900,y=900)
        ##########-----------line-------------##########
        Label(root,font=(30),fg='black',bg='grey',width=(3),height=(40)).place(x=1100,y=180)
        ##########-----------Bill-------------##########
        Label(root,text="Bill",font=('Arial',30),fg='black',bg='grey',width=(32)).place(x=1130,y=180)
        self.bill_text=Text(root)
        self.bill_text.insert("insert", "\n\nGreen Vegetables Market\n")
        self.bill_text.insert("end","One and only market where you can find Organic Vegetables\nSrikakulam, Andhrapradesh, 532484\nContact 9900887766\nGST no:X1234567890XYZ")
        self.bill_text.tag_add("head", "3.0", "3.23")
        self.bill_text.tag_add("rest", "4.0", "7.22")
        self.bill_text.tag_config("head", font=('Arial',30,'bold','underline'),justify='center')
        self.bill_text.tag_config("rest", font=('Arial',15),justify='center')
        self.bill_text.config(state='disabled',width=75,height=38)
        self.bill_text.place(x=1180,y=240)
        self.complete_and_save=Button(root,text="Complete and Save",font=('Arial',23),command=self.save_bill).place(x=1500,y=900)
    def calculate(self):
        if self.c_name.get()!='' and self.c_phno.get()!='' and self.c_add.get()!='':
            tot=0.0
            line=13.0
            self.bill_text.config(state='normal')
            self.bill_text.delete("8.0","end")
            for i in range(len(self.veg)):
                each_tot=0.0
                if self.ck[i].get()==1 and self.qty[i].get()>0:
                    self.bill_text.insert("end", "\nCustomer Details\n\tCustmor Name: "+self.c_name.get()+
                                            "\n\tContact number: "+self.c_phno.get()+"\n\tAddress: "+self.c_add.get())
                    self.bill_text.tag_add("details_head", "8.0","8.16")
                    self.bill_text.tag_config("details_head", font=('Arial',20,'underline'),justify='center')
                    self.bill_text.tag_add("details_body", "9.0","11.50")
                    self.bill_text.tag_config("details_body", font=('Arial',15),justify='left')
                    self.bill_text.insert("end", "\n\n"+"\t"+"item"+"\t\t"+"qty"+"\t\t"+"dis"+"\t\t"+"Total\n")
                    each_tot=each_tot+self.veg_price[i]*self.qty[i].get()
                    each_tot=each_tot-((each_tot/100)*self.dis[i].get())
                    self.each_price[i].config(text=str(each_tot)+" Rs")
                    tot=tot+each_tot
                    self.total_price.config(text=str(tot)+" Rs")
                    self.bill_text.config(state='normal')
                    self.bill_text.insert("end","\n"+"\t"+self.veg[i]+"\t\t"+str(self.qty[i].get())+"\t\t"+str(self.dis[i].get())+"\t\t"+str(each_tot))
                    self.bill_text.tag_add("items",str(line),"end")
                    self.bill_text.tag_config("items",font=('Arial',15),justify='left')
                    self.bill_text.config(state='disabled')
                    line=line+1
                else:
                    self.each_price[i].config(text="0 Rs")
                    self.qty[i].set(0)
                    self.dis[i].set(0)
            self.bill_text.config(state='normal')
            self.bill_text.insert("end", "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t   GST(18%) :"+"{:.2f}".format(((tot)/100)*18))
            self.bill_text.insert("end", "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t  Total amt :"+"{:.2f}".format((tot+((tot)/100)*18)))
            self.bill_text.config(state='disabled')         
    def close(self):
        exit()
    def clear(self):
        for i in range(len(self.veg)):
            self.ck[i].set(0)
            self.each_price[i].config(text="0 Rs")
            self.qty[i].set(0)
            self.dis[i].set(0)
        self.bill_text.config(state='normal')
        self.bill_text.delete("8.0","end")
        self.bill_text.config(state='disabled')
    def save_bill(self):
        import datetime
        from tkinter import messagebox
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now() 
        self.file_name=str(self.c_name)+str(current_time)
        self.file=open(self.file_name+".txt","w")
        self.file.write(self.bill_text.get("1.0","end"))
        self.file.close()
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Saved Successfully")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    win=tk.Tk()
    #title
    win.title("billing system")
    #setting tkinter window size
    width= win.winfo_screenwidth() 
    height= win.winfo_screenheight()
    win.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
    #bg color
    win.config(bg="black")

    app=App(win)
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is why `place` is rarely the right choice. If you use `pack` or `grid` it is much easier to make a responsive up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hardcoded (x, y) positions for all your widgets, so it only fits on *that resolution*.  Instead, you should have fullscreened, got window height & width info, then positioned widgets as **divisions of those dimensions**.

```
root .attributes( '-zoomed',  True )
root .update_idletasks()
Width, Height  = root .winfo_width(),  root .winfo_height()
```

---

```
self .clr = Button( root, text = "Clear", font = ( 'Arial', 23 ), bg = "yellow",
                    fg = "black", command = self .clear ) .place( x = 600, y = 900 )
```

should read something more along the lines of:

```
self .clr = Button( root, text = "Clear", font = ( 'Arial', 23 ), bg = "yellow",
                    fg = "black", command = self .clear ) .place( x = Width *0.5, y = Height *0.75 )
```

---

Or use `.grid()` instead of `.place()` - it does a lot of that for you --  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/